# How to install gulp on a docker with docker-compose

Tags: docker, gulp, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I am using docker compose and this is my yaml file

```
web:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
  build: .
  command: gulp
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - '9001:9001'
```

and here is my docker file

```
FROM node:0.12.7

RUN npm install -g bower gulp

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN bower install --allow-root
```

Then i run

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up
```

But i get the following error

```
Recreating web_web_1...
Attaching to web_web_1
web_1 | [07:39:08] Local gulp not found in /app
web_1 | [07:39:08] Try running: npm install gulp
web_web_1 exited with code 1
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)**strong text**
```

I have tried adding the line `RUN npm install gulp` before and after `WORKDIR /app` to get it installed locally but i get the same error

Help

Comment: I know nothing about gulp, but your Dockerfile should end with a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` I think, see https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd and https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to **run `npm install gulp` AFTER `WORKDIR /app`**, so that gulp is installed locally in `node_modules/gulp`. But you already did that and having the same error. It's because in your `docker-compose-dev.yml`, **you are mounting host directory as `/app` volume inside docker container**. So local changes in /app directory is lost when you are running the container.

You can either remove volumes from `docker-compose-dev.yml` or run `npm install gulp` in host machine.

Comment: This was spot on, thanks so much. i have literally spent 1.5 days working on this

Comment: This is it. Removing the `volumes` section made the container run. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `startup.sh`

```
npm install bower gulp
bower install --allow-root
```

(or whatever you need to run when container fires) then your Dockerfile should execute startup.sh

```
...
CMD ["/startup.sh"]
```

the startup script will be executed AFTER the dir is mounted by docker-compose.

I would also suggest to mount node_modules in the temporary file system declaring in the docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
- .:/app
- /app/node_modules
```